# how to review who accessed the db in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

our contract with a outsourced company fell apart, and they seemed to access the rails console in production. We have a backup, we are able to restore the data. But we need to make sure that who accessed the rails console.

```
development:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 database: xxxx-xxx
 host: xxx.xx.xx.xx
 pool: 5
 username: xxxx
 password: xxxx
```

in host if we change the ip, and give the appropriate user name and password, we will be able to connect to production data.

So is there a way, we can see the logs of who accessed the database through console?

ps: SSH into server is not possible as the passwords are changed recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there a way, we can see the logs of who accessed the database through console?

About the only log where this can be stored is your DB server log (in form of "open new connection from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"). That's as far as you can get, I think.

In any case, tracking rails console access doesn't make sense. Rails console can only access data if credentials in database.yml are valid. And if credentials in their database.yml are valid, they **don't need** the rails console to do all kinds of nasty things to your DB. They can just use `psql` directly or any other client.

Change DB credentials immediately.

Comment: The thing is we forgot to change the database password, but we have blocked all the ssh access. And the damage is already done, they deleted the user data in production. So what can be done to prove that they have deleted the data?

Comment: @gates: apart from inspecting database logs, I have no idea. Maybe hire forensics experts?

Comment: May I know how to access those database logs, if you don't mind .. please

Comment: @gates: how am I supposed to know? It's your server, your configuration. :) If you host the db yourself, ask your DBA. If you pay for a hosted solution, ask your service provider.